# FreeNX is very unresponsive compare to VNC when using over LAN

Tags: nx-client, freenx

I find FreeNX is quite unresponsive compare to VNC when using over LAN.
I run Netbeans inside a Quad Core Server and remote desktop to it through both NX & VNC.
For VNC, the screen will be nicely updated as I scroll the Netbean IDE
For FreeNX, flickering happened and the mouse cursor become unresponsive as I tried to do the samething.
Have anyone encountered the same?
I don't like VNC because when VNC doesnot correctly understand the "Windows" key (interpreted as `Super L` instead of `Mod`)

Is there any adjustment that can avoid that annoyance?

I have tried both FreeNX-Server and NeatX-Server and both resulted in the same unresponsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I have found the answer over there: http://brunovernay.wordpress.com/2007/12/11/remote-access-to-netbeans/
The solution is to modify netbeans.conf (which would be found in $NETBEAN_INSTaLL_DIR/etc/netbeans.conf) and change the 
`netbeans_default_options` so that it will contains `-J-Dsun.java2d.pmoffscreen=false`

Thanks to google.